# OSX Deployment Target in Cmakelists.txt

Tags: macos, qt, deployment, cmake, target

So I created a GUI app using Cmake on my Mac running 10.13 and when I tried to run it on another Mac using 10.11 it didn't work because of the OS. So I set in Cmakelists.txt set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.8" CACHE STRING "Minimum OS X deployment version")

After doing that and rebuilding, it worked on the 10.11 Mac. After trying it on a Mac that runs 10.10.5 however, it did not work. I don't understand how setting it to 10.8 changed it to allow it to work on the 10.11 but not 10.10. What am I missing? cmake version 3.11.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I forgot to add that this is also a Qt app. You see, adding the minimum deployment target in Cmakelists.txt to 10.8 and also setting it in Xcode to 10.8 is all fine and dandy. But when you use Qt 5.11 for the app, it will only support down to OSX 10.11 regardless of what your deployment target is due to Qt 5.11 not supporting below OSX 10.11 according to their website. What I did was install Qt 5.5 and reset the paths in the Cmakelists to where Qt 5.5 is. I installed it by running **brew install qt@5.5** in the terminal.

Qt's website says that Qt 5.5 supports OSX 10.8 - 10.10. This was all I needed. I now have 2 builds of the app one supporting 10.11-10.13 and the other supporting 10.8-10.10. Oddly enough the app built for 10.8 - 10.10 also runs on 10.13. Don't know if this was intended or if I'm just stupid and missing something.